# A question about the definition of complete dg Lie algebras in a paper of Lazarev and Markl

Tags: model-categories, rational-homotopy-theory, differential-graded-lie-algebras

In their paper [Disconnected Rational Homotopy Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1037), Lazarev and Markl give the following definition (page 23):

> **Definition:** A *complete differential graded Lie algebra* is an inverse limit of finite-dimensional, nilpotent differential graded Lie algebras (dgla).

The limit here is taken in the category of dglas, which is complete (and cocomplete). However, a couple of lines later, they show that complete dglas are pronilpotent assuming, apparently without loss of generality, that any complete dgla is a *sequential* limit of finite-dimensional nilpotent dglas, which I strongly believe is a more stringent condition that being an arbitrary limit. So what am I missing? Is the definition incorrect as stated (in the sense that we allow only some special kinds of limits), is the proof that complete dglas are pronilpotent wrong, or is there some implication or equivalence between various kinds of limits in the category of dglas that I don't know about?

In particular, I am interested to the model structure that they put on the category of complete dglas a bit later in the paper (page 36). We need the category to be complete and cocomplete, and if we can take arbitrary limits then completeness is obvious, while if we only allow e.g. sequential limits I'm not sure it holds.

I will be grateful for any contribution.

**Remark:** Cross-posted from [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1772980/60713).

Comment: I haven't thought about the details, but I don't see anywhere that they actually use the fact that it's a sequential limit. If you just replace their $\text{lim}_n$ with a general filtered limit, is there anything that doesn't work?

Comment: @JeremyRickard They explicitly use the fact that they're taking a filtered limit (ok, it's more general that just a sequential limit, but it's still not as general as we'd like...) I cite: "Since the filtered limit of finite-dimensional vector spaces is
exact, we easily verify that $g_k\cong\lim_n(g_n)_k$." (**Remark:** I left away a superscript $n$, which I believe was a typo.)